# How to properly fire browser events from within python using boost and Firebreath

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python, firebreath

first I must say that as a Python programmer, I might be seeing this problem from a wrong perspective, many years had passed since I wrote my last c++ code back in college.

I'm having a bit of a problem, trying to create a hybrid python/c++ plugin using firebreath. I've been succesfull so far integrating all the parts using boost/python.h, but a problem arose when I tried to fire an event from within python. I stumbled with the problem of having to bind together a python function with a c++ function (using the BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE). First I tried to bind directly python with my JSAPI derived class fbtestconpythonAPI, the problem with this approach seems to be the lack of reference to the JSAPI object instantiated by the browser, giving me all kinds of signature mismatch problems between python function and c++ equivalent at execution time.

The only thing that ocurred to me to fix this( I agree, is an ugly dirty solution), is to use a global pointer which I initialize by hand with set_pluginPointer. This actually works pretty well so far, but I know it is not the right way to do it. I read that I should not be using a "raw" pointer with a JSAPI object, but I'm not sure how to replace it with a shared_ptr for this particular implementation. Another problem is the global variable, wich is shared accross all instances, causing for example, that all events are fired on the last tab/window opened. One way to solve the latter would be creating some sort of array with an index being the current window/thread id, wich is something I should be able to access from both my JSAPI object and python/c++ function.

Of course I'm open, and will apreciate very much, any suggestions, on how to improve/fix either this particular workaround or, better, the correct way to communicate boost::python and firebreath without hacking.

Below is the relevant part of the plugin code

```
// Global pointer to plugin instance
fbtestconpythonAPI *fbtestPtr;
void fbtestconpythonAPI::set_pluginPointer(const std::string& val){
    m_testString = val;
    fbtestPtr = this; //Global pointer initialization
}

void echo(std::string x){
    // Firing the echo event on the plugin instance using the global raw pointer
    fbtestPtr->fire_echo(x, 1);
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Pointless) {
    def("echo", echo);
}

FB::variant fbtestconpythonAPI::echo(const FB::variant& msg){
    int result_value;
    Py_Initialize(); 

    try {
        initPointless(); // initialize Pointless

        PyRun_SimpleString("import Pointless");
        PyRun_SimpleString("Pointless.echo('hello world')");

        object module(handle<>(borrowed(PyImport_AddModule("__main__"))));
        object dictionary = module.attr("__dict__");
    } catch (error_already_set) {
        PyErr_Print();
    }

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't worked with Boost.Python yet, but it seems you should investigate how to get Python objects bound to FireBreath plugin instances instead of trying to get the workaround (free functions + globals) working. I recommend asking a question about that initial problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Maybe I was not very clear, please forgive me as English is not my first language, what I meant is that any kind of suggestion on how to do this (connect boost:python with firebreath) will be highly appreciated. I just wanted to share the solution I came up with, to rule that out from the answers

Comment: I see, then i just misunderstood you.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look you'd setup your class for export like this:

```
class_<YourAPI, boost::noncopyable>("YourAPI", no_init)
    .def("function", &YourAPI::function);
```

Then you can pass [a reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/python/doc/v2/ptr.html#ptr-spec) to your C++ instance to Python, allowing you to call functions on it which in turn can fire events.

Comment: Thanks very much Georg. I'll start looking into that right away